# SocialEngine db structure/explanation

Tags: socialengine

I'm new to `socialEngine` and a client of mine asked me to modify his website which is using `socialEngine`. He is using this CMS for over 6 years now and since then, it has never been modified.

I'm trying to reduce the size of database tables which are really huge.

For example,

the whole db is around 2G,

`engine4_user_logins` is 435MiB,

`engine4_user_fields_search` is 615MiB and

`engine4_authorization_allow` is 234MiB.

I searched for socialEngine db structure but I couldn't find it. I'm not asking you to explain every single table in database. My questions are:

Is it safe to empty these tables? And why are these tables so full?! Is it because of the long time that no modification applied to them?!

Answer (score 1):

It's safe to clear `engine4_user_logins` however that data in that table is used in statistics section in SocialEngine's admin panel. You can clear it but you'll loose stats data. Don't clear the other two tables. SE uses 
`engine4_authorization_allow` for item permissions and `engine4_user_fields_search` for searching.

`engine4_authorization_allow` and `engine4_user_fields_search` get populated when items are created in SocialEngine. blogs, users, groups, photos, etc. That's why they're huge.

If client is having performance issues, I suggest tweaking server configurations or upgrading the server.